# Лексические значения "выступающего" и "выдающегося"

Tags: лексика

Можно ли употреблять слова "выступающий" и "выдающийся" в значении "отличный от других", "замечательный"?

Например: выступающая своими необычными формами плитка
или
выдающийся своей расцветкой пазл.

Answer (score 1):

В ваших примерах правильнее было бы употребить глагол **выделяющаяся** (на фоне чего-либо) и **привлекающий** (внимание): "выступающая" воспринимается буквально, геометрически (будто её "необычные формы" выходят за какой-то условный габарит), а "выдающаяся" наоборот, воспринимается в переносном смысле (неординарный), с которым не сочетается уточнение "чем именно".